# How to detect which shortcut(s) are mapped to a specific command in Vim?

Tags: python, vim, plugins

In short, I'd like to provide a help window in a Vim plugin that can detect which shortcuts the user mapped to the plugin's commands in their .vimrc.

Is there a way to see which shortcuts a user may or may not have mapped to a plugin command?

(Note, I'm **not** looking for a way to see what command a specific shortcut will execute, which is an FAQ easily found).

For example, in a user's .vimrc, they can add a line such as:

```
map <leader>1 :MyCoolPluginCommand<cr>
```

And in my plugin interface I want to surface a quick help window that displays a cheetsheet such as

```
"Cool Command 1: <leader>1"
```

My only thought would be to try and parse their vimrc and use a complicated set of regular expressions to grab string values.  Any better way?  Thanks!

**[edit]** The plugin calls out to a python script, so I also tagged this question with python in the event that makes a solution possible. (Using `import vim` so I can eval() stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:map` gives you a list of all mappings; it should be easier to parse than .vimrc.

Also it will show mappings coming from other places (eg system-wide or command-line).

Comment: Gotcha, I'll parse it in python and that should work.  Thanks!

Comment: you can use something like `:redir @a | map` and then `"ap` so you can paste the contents of `:map` in a regular file, which will make it easier for you to search the text you want.